# How to call Inet_StateChange in VB6?

Tags: ftp, vb6, inet

I have 2 forms in my vb6 project, it starts loading the Form 1 then Form 2.

In form 1, I have a timer. (I'm using this for other function).
In form 2, I have an Inet and Inet1_StateChanged.  Every time it executes, it will go to my Form 1 timer.

First Question, How can I execute the Inet1_StateChanged?  Second, Why is it going to Form 1 every time Inet1 executes?

This is the code for my Inet in form 2:

```
With Inet1
    .AccessType = icUseDefault
    .Protocol = icFTP
    .URL = "" & ftphost & ""
    .username = "" & ftpuser & ""
    .password = "" & ftppass & ""
    .Execute , "PUT  " & File_PATH & "" & fname & "  " & ftphostpath & "" & fname & ""
End With
```

Thank you in advance for your response!

Comment: I don't think you have added enough code... to understand the connection between form1 and form2; can you add the full _StateChanged event handler from form2, and also the timer code from form1 ?

Comment: Just guessing, but this might be a helpful example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14258862/3195477

Comment: If Form1 receives the focus again, it's because you (most likely) have code in your timer event causing it. As @StayOnTarget already mentioned: not enough code shown. As for how to execute `Inet1_StateChanged`, well this is en event. Typically you don't execute these directly, but rather something your code does or external factors trigger an event, which then executes the code you wrote in that event's procedure. Like a command button's click event `Command1_Click()` gets triggered by (amongst other things) clicking on it.

Answer (score 3):

Inet1_StateChanged .. is an event, yo do not manually execute events. It is triggered by "state change" of inet1. List of state change events from the help file... If you wish you can share more info about your code so i(we) can look at it?

| event | code | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| icNone | 0 | No state to report. |
| icHostResolvingHost | 1 | The control is looking up the IP address of the specified host computer. |
| icHostResolved | 2 | The control successfully found the IP address of the specified host computer. |
| icConnecting | 3 | The control is connecting to the host computer. |
| icConnected | 4 | The control successfully connected to the host computer. |
| icRequesting | 5 | The control is sending a request to the host computer. |
| icRequestSent | 6 | The control successfully sent the request. |
| icReceivingResponse | 7 | The control is receiving a response from the host computer. |
| icResponseReceived | 8 | The control successfully received a response from the host computer. |
| icDisconnecting | 9 | The control is disconnecting from the host computer. |
| icDisconnected | 10 | The control successfully disconnected from the host computer. |
| icError | 11 | An error occurred in communicating with the host computer. |
| icResponseCompleted | 12 | The request has completed and all data has been received. |